# How should I handle money returned for a product that I did not return?

Tags: credit-card, debit-card, online-payment, refund, purchase

I purchased a laptop online through the official website, my card was charged immediately after I made payment. The item arrived around two weeks after that.

I checked my banking app and discovered that the money was returned two days before the item arrived saying that it's a reversal payment. I have contacted the company from whom I purchased the laptop and they said that they have received the payment and that I should refer to my bank. My bank said to contact the seller as they have forwarded the payment and suspected an error on the company's behalf.

It has been three months and I have not been charged even a single penny. How should I proceed?

Additional note: I never initiated any return procedure even by accident since after finalizing the payment I never checked on the status of my order and I was notified of the products arrival through my mobile phone.

Comment: Is it a debit-card or a credit card? you attached both tags.

Comment: I actually have no idea but I guess it's a virtual debit card since I have to have the amount before I can use it, I am very new to this kind of things.

Comment: A debit card removes the money immediately from a linked bank account. A credit card requires a monthly payment.

Comment: I recommend you check your credit rating at the major houses (Equifax, Experian, or equivalent in your home country) to make sure nobody has filed a report on this purchase.

Comment: On a related note, a few months ago Amazon billed my card for a purchase I made in late 2017! After quite some investigation we determined that Amazon had shipped my purchase back then without ever having billed me, which I hadn't noticed at the time, and they finally got around to it, more than two years later. You also might find this charge coming back unexpectedly some time in the future.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I had the opposite experience, for the first part at least - I had an Amazon return and almost a year later I noticed that although Amazon said they refunded the purchase I never received the money in my bank account.  I never bothered to chase it down because it was for something like $10 but who knows, maybe in a couple more years it will show up!

Answer (score 47):

In my opinion, you've done more than you need to do.

Some would argue that you didn't need to do anything at all.  It wasn't your fault that payment was reversed and it is the job of the seller to take care of that.

You've informed the seller that you don't believe you were charged for the laptop.  You don't need to do anything else. Let them take care of it if they choose to do so.

You may get a free laptop out of the situation, but you've done nothing wrong so you don't need to feel guilty about it!

Comment: But the OP should keep the money aside for quite a while (years - the exact time may depend on jurisdiction) in case they ask for it after all.

Comment: I would suggest investing it, but that's not really _aside_. I wonder whether there are any risk-free investments (i.e. ones where the risk is covered by somebody else)?

Comment: @wizzwizz4: A treasury bond is probably the closest equivalent. They are technically at risk of default if the US government decides not to pay them off, but this has never happened and they are widely regarded as very safe investments. However, if you plan to sell early, you might have to worry about the yield curve inverting.

Comment: I think a savings account is probably the nearest you can get to a risk-free investment.

Comment: But AFAIK US "Savings" account gives you no interest... or functionally no interest for the amount of a typical laptop.

Comment: *"Some would argue that you didn't need to do anything at all."* - in many jurisdictions, keeping money that you received by error and which you know doesn't belong to you, can land you in prison. See e.g.: [1](https://www.thisismoney.co.uk/money/news/article-1621108/Mum-jailed-after-Abbeys-135k-blunder.html), [2](https://www.thesun.co.uk/news/7754721/dad-christmas-bank-error/), [3](https://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2594460/Young-mother-benefits-went-designer-spending-spree-52-000-just-hours-council-accidentally-credited-account-escaped-jail.html).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I am just afraid that they will ask the money when I no longer have it and since my country's currency is rather weak and tend to get weaker over time they might charge more than the previous price, as I bought the laptop when I was overseas. I was planning on investing it but need some second opinion whether or not it would be a good idea.

Comment: @kroent That's kind of a different question. In that case the answer might be that you should keep the money on an account that is in the same currency as you paid your laptop in. But how much is your currency realistically going to devalue in the next couple of months or maybe a year? After that you might still be liable, but it becomes increasingly unlikely they will ask for their money.

Comment: Yes. If when you discovered the error you had done nothing and hoped that no one would notice, that would be unethical and probably illegal. But if you notify the company about the error and they do nothing, and you notify the bank about the error and they do nothing, what more are you supposed to do? Presumably either the seller or the bank will eventually find that they are short the money, but as I assume it's a few hundred dollars and not millions they'll likely end up writing it off.

Comment: @JBentley In all three of the examples you gave, the person in question was in hot water because they _spent_ the money, not because they _kept_ it.  While your statement may still be true, none of those are supporting evidence.

Comment: @GrandOpener They are supporting evidence because they were convicted for the crime of *theft*. Spending is irrelevant for theft (at least in the UK). Theft Act 1968 section 1(2): "It is immaterial whether the appropriation is made with a view to gain, or is made for the thief’s own benefit.". What matters is that there is appropriation, dishonesty, property belonging to another, and intention to permenantly deprive (section 1(1), sections 2 - 6). These elements are all present if you knowingly keep money sent to you in error (again, according to precedents established in UK law).

Comment: @JBentley "Intention to permanently deprive" is the key here.  If you spend the money, you clearly establish that intention.  If you leave the money in the bank account, available to return if necessary, that's a clear signal there is not intention to permanently deprive.  Hoping they don't ask for it back is not legally "intention to deprive."  You say there is precedent?  If there is precedent in UK law for someone receiving money in error, keeping that money in reserve so that it could be returned if necessary, and still being charged, please share that precedent.

Comment: @GrandOpener Intention here has a very specific meaning, and using lay logic is rarely advisable when it comes to law. Intention can include "borrowing" if the period of time is equivalent to an outright taking (Theft Act s 6(1)). The courts have previously held that taking and returning an item to a shop can be theft because you have prevented the shop from selling it in that time. If you leave money in the bank, knowing full well who the owner is, and don't bother returning it or even informing that person (despite that both are trivially easy) [cont...]

Comment: @GrandOpener ... a prosecutor is going to have very little trouble establishing intention. Its also quite clear that you hoped to get away with it and that the owner wouldn't notice anything. Note that I said "can" land you in prison. I did not claim this exact scenario has been examined by the courts. But you would be a fool to risk it, and that's something just about any criminal lawyer would agree with. This is getting way off topic, I suggest a post on law stackexchange if you want to take it further.

Comment: @JBentley Seems like a good idea.  I've taken your suggestion: https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/58831/is-failing-to-report-a-bank-error-in-and-of-itself-a-crime

Answer (score 2):

Open a savings account at an online bank, as a "holding tank" for the money you'd have used to pay for the laptop.  Then if the vendor realizes their mistake and charges you again then you'll have the money.

If after a year they haven't reversed it, I'd take that as a sign that they aren't coming back for it.

Comment: Thank you, so 9 months to go it is . I am really afraid they might charge more for the laptop since I bought it overseas using a card from my country which has a low exchange rate.

Comment: @kroent I hope you kept the receipt!!

Comment: This is way more work than you should put into dealing with the seller's bookkeeping problem for them. Just keep the money wherever you already keep your money.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE opening a savings account at an online bank is **trivially simple**.  (In the US, at least.  Maybe it's still hard in financial backwaters like Europe.)

Comment: @RonJohn: Only if you're already using that bank. If you're not, even if they claim to make it simple, you have to be *satisfy yourself* that you're going to be able to access your money and get it back. Just the research to determine that is a ridiculous amount of work.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE not true.  I've opened accounts at new banks pretty quickly, and immediately transferred money in.  Getting the money out was easy, too.

Comment: @RonJohn: Getting it out may be easy. Determining that it's going to be easy is not easy unless you already know that. There is a highly nontrivial amount of research involved in convincing yourself of that if you don't just trust someone who says it's so. And I guarantee it's not easy if you don't have a SSN, or your name doesn't match what the bank's verification system thinks it should be, or you have no credit/banking-system history at all, or any number of other potential problems.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE "it's not easy if you don't have a SSN".  Now you're being absurdly picky. "There is a highly nontrivial amount of research involved".  Hogwash.  Nerdwallet, Bankrate, etc all have lists of highly rated banks.

Comment: @RonJohn: Knowing any of those names and whether they're trustworthy or will tell me if I'm going to get stuck with my money in a bank I can't access without spending hours on the phone with customer service is ASTRONOMICALLY MORE WORK THAN ANYONE SHOULD SPEND TO DEAL WITH OP'S NON-PROBLEM THAT'S SOMEONE ELSE'S PROBLEM.

Comment: Wait, if the money is in another account, then if they charge back your original account you risk getting overdrawn if your balance happens to be below whatever the laptop cost. Should the original account be closed to prevent this from happening?

Comment: @Michael the question says "my card was **charged** immediately", and has **both** the `debit-card` **and** `credit-card` tags, but also says "the money was returned two days before the item arrived".  OP doesn't know whether he used a DC or CC.